# Symfony2 and postgresql

Tags: symfony, postgresql-9.1

I want to create a project using symfony2 with postgresql, but when I run the command: ***php app/console doctrine:database:create*** I got the error: ***Could create database named "test", could not find driver,*** I know It has something with drivers but I made sure wampserver load php_pdo_pgsql,
this is my parameters.yml file:

```
database_driver: pdo_pgsql
database_host: 127.0.0.1
database_port: 5432
database_name: test
database_user: postgres
database_password: openpgpwd
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
mailer_user: null
mailer_password: null
locale: en
secret: eb10e110d2a3c3f3f5df66181eb10376109f
database_path: null
```

Comment: Do you find an entry for pqsql in your phpinfo() output?

Comment: yea I do find both pdo_pgsql and pgsql

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Tested on Symfony 2.7. In parameters.yml the database_driver does not work. To make postgre work with Symfony, in config.yml find

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:   pdo_mysql
```

And change it to

```
doctrine:
  dbal:
    driver:   pdo_pgsql
```

That should do the trick. You can get rid of database_driver in parameters.yml or use it as you change pdo_mysql to %database_driver% .
There is no need to tell that the php postgresql module is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved it by installing php-pgsql

Comment: Which Driver you have Selected while installing.?